# what can't I group a DataFrame by every column

Tags: python, pandas

I used to perform this type of operation to eliminate duplicate records in my DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [669, 1, 2003, 2],
    [673, 1, 2003, 2],
    [675, 1, 2004, 1],
    [739, 1, 2004, 1],
    [741, 1, 2003, 1],
    [773, 1, 2004, 1],
    [791, 1, 2004, 1],
    [794, 1, 2004, 1],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
dfg = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
dff = dfg.first().reset_index()

print pd.__version__
print

print df
print
print dff
print
```

The output looks like:

```
0.15.1

     A  B     C  D
0  669  1  2003  2
1  673  1  2003  2
2  675  1  2004  1
3  739  1  2004  1
4  741  1  2003  1
5  773  1  2004  1
6  791  1  2004  1
7  794  1  2004  1

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, C, D]
Index: []
```

You can see the dff DataFrame is empty.  I don't understand why.

However, If I add a dummy column 'E' and group by everything else and then slice only the columns I want, all is well.

```
df_ = df.copy()
df_['E'] = 'E'
dfg_ = df_.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
dff_ = dfg_.first().reset_index()

print df_[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]
print
print dff_[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]
```

And I get this output:

```
     A  B     C  D
0  669  1  2003  2
1  673  1  2003  2
2  675  1  2004  1
3  739  1  2004  1
4  741  1  2003  1
5  773  1  2004  1
6  791  1  2004  1
7  794  1  2004  1

     A  B     C  D
0  669  1  2003  2
1  673  1  2003  2
2  675  1  2004  1
3  739  1  2004  1
4  741  1  2003  1
5  773  1  2004  1
6  791  1  2004  1
7  794  1  2004  1
```

So my questions are these:

1. Was this an intentional change in pandas 0.15.1?
2. Is there a better or more appropriate way to eliminate duplicate records in my DataFrame?

Thanks,
PiR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I'm afraid I can't answer
2. Yes, you can use `df.drop_duplicates()` ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)) You can also pass it a `subset` list of column names so as to drop duplicates from those columns.